# ROS on Ubuntu Loki, Elementary OS. Problem installing

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, ubuntu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The message looks like the following

```
W: The repository 'http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu loki Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-updates/universe/binary-amd64/by-hash/SHA256/db842801ebf6a595ffdef380db19d15a14119f4cf3e9fb7fa26951854def60c1  Hash Sum mismatch
E: Failed to fetch http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/dists/loki/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 140.211.166.134 80]
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
supratim@Floyd:~$ sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-desktop-full
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package ros-kinetic-desktop-full
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/272787/ros-on-ubuntu-loki,-elementary-os.-problem-installing/) by [Supratim](https://answers.ros.org/users/32213/supratim/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-10-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Afaik, `Ubuntu Loki` is not an actual Ubuntu release. It's a release of Elementary OS.

The ROS buildfarm does not build any packages for Elementary OS specifically, so that's why `apt` cannot download a *Release file* for it.

To install ROS on Elementary OS Loki (which is based on Ubuntu Xenial (16.04)), you could try two things:

1. change `loki` to `xenial` in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-latest.list`
2. override OS detection in all ROS tools by setting the environment variable `ROS_OS_OVERRIDE` to `ubuntu:16.04:xenial` (see [wiki/EnvironmentVariables - ROS_OS_OVERRIDE](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/EnvironmentVariables#ROS_OS_OVERRIDE) for more info).

After fixing point 1, you can try to `apt-get update` again and see whether your packages will install.

With 2, tools like `rosdep` should work.

Note that as Elementary OS is not an officially supported distribution, you could run into compatibility issues. But the only way to know is to try it.

---

See #q40081 for a related question btw.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-10-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1